Entropy change of an isolated system consisting of two thermally conductive blocks of equal isochoric heat capacity at different temperatures
A classic example considered in most introductory treatments of elementary thermodynamics consists of two thermally conductive (e.g., metal) blocks placed in thermal contact. In particular, I find this setup mentioned in the first half of page 56 of Enrico Fermi's classic Thermodynamics, in point 2 of page 77 of H. C. Van Ness' Understanding Thermodynamics, and in this answer (along with its comments) on Physics Stack Exchange. In all such cases, the reasoning seems to proceed as follows:
Given an isolated system consisting of two thermally conductive objects $B_1$ and $B_2$ (say, two homogeneous metal blocks of identical isochoric heat capacity $C_V$) at respective temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$ with $T_1 > T_2$ which are held separately at thermal equilibrium then brought into thermal contact, we observe an amount of heat $Q$ to be transferred from $B_1$ to $B_2$. We may then express the entropy change of this isolated system as
$$\Delta S = \frac{Q_1}{T_1} + \frac{Q_2}{T_2} = \frac{-Q}{T_1} + \frac{Q}{T_2} = -\frac{Q}{T_1} + \frac{Q}{T_2} = Q\left ( \frac{1}{T_2} - \frac{1}{T_1} \right ) = Q \left ( \frac{T_1 - T_2}{T_1 T_2} \right ) > 0,$$
illustrating the Second Law of Thermodynamics. This may be expressed 'differentially' as well:
Since the system is isolated and performs no work, we may use the First Law to write $ \mathrm{d} U_1 = \delta Q_1 $ and $ \mathrm{d} U_2 = -\mathrm{d} U_1 > 0$, so that
$$ \mathrm{d}S = \frac{\delta Q_1}{T_1} + \frac{\delta Q_2}{T_2} = \frac{\mathrm{d} U_1}{T_1} + \frac{\mathrm{d} U_2}{T_2} = \mathrm{d} U_1 \left (\frac{1}{T_1} - \frac{1}{T_2} \right )>0$$
On the other hand, couldn't we just as well analyze this process as follows:
Since the heat transfer is isobaric as well as isochoric, we have (cf. Fermi page 21),
$$ \mathrm{d} U = \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}~ \mathrm{d} T + \frac{\partial U}{\partial V}~ \mathrm{d} V = \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}~ \mathrm{d} T = C_V~ \mathrm{d} T \Longrightarrow \Delta U = C_V \Delta T,$$
so that $\Delta U_1 = C_V (T_1 - {T_{\text{avg}}})$ and $\Delta U_2 = C_V ({T_{\text{avg}}}-T_2)$ where ${T_{\text{avg}}}$ denotes the final (equilibrium) temperature attained by the system of two blocks at the conclusion of the heat exchange, given by the arithmetic mean of the two initial temperatures ${T_{\text{avg}}} = \frac{T_1 + T_2}{2}$. Then, once again using the First Law in the isochoric case $\mathrm{d} U_k = \delta Q_k = \mathrm{d} Q_k$ for $k\in\{1,2\}$ (so that $Q_k$ can be taken to be a state function by equality with the state function $U_k$), we may write
$$ \Delta S_k = \int_{T_k}^{T_{\text{avg}}} \frac{\mathrm{d} Q_k}{T}=\int_{T_k}^{T_{\text{avg}}} \frac{\mathrm{d}U_k}{T} = \int_{T_k}^{T_{\text{avg}}} \frac{C_V ~\mathrm{d}T}{T} = C_V \ln \frac{{T_{\text{avg}}}}{T_k}$$
for $k \in \{1,2\}$, so that
$$ \Delta S = \Delta S_1 + \Delta S_2 = C_V \left ( \ln \frac{{T_{\text{avg}}}}{T_1} + \ln \frac{{T_{\text{avg}}}}{T_2} \right ) = C_V \ln \frac{{T_{\text{avg}}}^2}{T_1 T_2} $$
$$= C_V \ln \left ( \frac{T_1^2 + 2T_1 T_2 + T_2^2}{4T_1 T_2 } \right ) = C_V \ln \left ( \frac{T_1^2+ T_2^2}{4T_1 T_2 } + \frac{1}{2} \right ) .$$
Is the above analysis somehow also correct? If not, then why not? But if so, then is there some difference in perspective which has produced the apparent discrepancy between these two results for $\Delta S$?

See example 1 in the following link: https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/

The first analysis is an approximation for cases in which only a small amount of heat is transferred between the blocks (after which they are separated).  The second analysis applies to the cases where enough heat is transferred for the blocks to equilibrate thermally.
In general, for two bodies, $$\Delta S_H=mC\ln{\left(\frac{T_{Hf}}{T_{Hi}}\right)}$$ and $$\Delta S_C=mC\ln{\left(\frac{T_{Cf}}{T_{Ci}}\right)}$$ From the first law of thermodynamics, $$T_{Hf}=T_{H_i}-\frac{Q}{mC}$$and$$T_{Cf}=T_{C_i}-\frac{Q}{mC}$$where Q is the amount of heat transferred from the hot body to the cold body.  If we substitute these into the equations for the entropy changes, we obtain:$$\Delta S_H=mC\ln{\left(1-\frac{Q}{mCT_{Hi}}\right)}$$and$$\Delta S_C=mC\ln{\left(1+\frac{Q}{mCT_{Ci}}\right)}$$If we linearize these equations to get the limit at small Q, we obtain $$\Delta S_H\approx -\frac{Q}{T_{Hi}}$$and$$\Delta S_C\approx +\frac{Q}{T_{Ci}}$$

You've solved the case of a finite temperature change to the arithmetic mean, for finite objects. The first equation gives the entropy increase for an infinitesimal amount of heating (equivalently, heating between reservoirs of infinite extent), such that the temperatures remain unchanged. (They converge to both predict $\Delta S\to 0$ as $T_2\to T_1$.)

I see what you mean re the correspondence of the two solutions in the limit as $T_2 \to T_1$, but I don't see how the first $\Delta S$ corresponds to 'infinitesimal heating.' That's certainly not how that result was discussed by Fermi or Van Ness in the textbooks I cited.

Both authors earlier introduce the differential form $dS\sim\frac{1}{T}$ and its integral, so since they're now using $\Delta S\sim\frac{1}{T_1}$ or  $\Delta S\sim\frac{1}{T_2}$ with a system's single temperature in the denominator—in other words, since they've already brought the temperature outside the integral—than they can only be talking about that system being at an essentially constant temperature. Thus, the heating must be negligible or the systems very large (or both) for the purpose of those examples. $\Delta S$ for finite temperature changes is discussed elsewhere in both books.

So the essence of the distinction is that the first $\Delta S$ regards the blocks $B_k$ as constant temperature thermal reservoirs (whether due to enormous size or brevity of contact), whereas the second $\Delta S$ is the equilibrium solution for blocks of finite size which have been left in thermal contact for sufficient time to establish equilibrium at $T_{\text{avg}}$.

Precisely. You may enjoy a note I wrote about what happens if the objects are instead connected by a Carnot heat engine, and what happens with more than 2 objects, including how hot we can possibly make a third object by leveraging the original temperature differences.

Apologies for the delayed response: I did get around to reading your note, but became confused about halfway through by the crucial step at which you produce the titular result that $T_{\text{final}} = \sqrt{T_1 T_2}$ from the equality $T_{\text{final}} / T_1 = T_{\text{final}} / T_2$. Wouldn't the latter equation require that $T_1 = T_2$? Am I correct in assuming that you meant to write $T_1 / T_{\text{final}}  = T_{\text{final}} / T_2$?

Thank you very much for spotting this typo. I owe you one.

Sure thing! I really enjoyed the note by the way. It got me thinking about the sum occurring in the discrete Clausius inequality: If we take the irreversible case and suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^n Q_k / T_k < 0$, this implies that $\sum_{k=1}^n Q_k / T_k = r$ for some $r < 0$. If the respective heat transfers $Q_k$ in the sum all happened to be equal $Q_k = Q ~\forall ~k \in {1,...,n}$ then it looks to me like the quantity of heat $Q$ conferred to the system by each of the reservoirs would be (negatively) proportional to the harmonic mean of the reservoir temperatures $T_1,...,T_n$.

This left me wondering if there might also be a setup analogous to the ones you demonstrated in your note for the arithmetic and geometric means which produces the harmonic mean as the entropy change or heat flux (or whatever) associated with some thermodynamic process.

You might consider posting this as a question, to provide enough space to explain the scenario clearly. For example, I'm not sure how many objects and reservoirs are present and how they're interacting.
